# mono for android Using Native Libraries

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am new to Mono for Android project, and I need to use it in my current project. I want to ask, how can I make some native library on Java for Android and attach it in Mono for Android project on C#? I read some articles on stackoverflow, but didn't find answer for me. And also I read:

http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Using_Native_Libraries

and I can't get what "libfoo.so" means and how to create it? What is the *.so extention mean? 
I would thank for some real experience to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "native" library in this case refers to a library written in C/C++ (you can think of a .so file as a DLL for C/C++). That said, it sounds like you actually want to bind a Java library, rather than a C library. Xamarin provides some tooling that allows you to create bindings for Java libraries, and have a guide available here: [Binding a Java Library (.jar)](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29)